# How to read json string from gzip

Tags: python, json, gzip

I am trying to read a json object from a .gz file.

Here is the code:

```
with gzip.open("C:/Users/shaya/Downloads/sample.gz", 'rb') as fin:
    json_bytes = fin.read()  
    
json_str = json_bytes.decode('utf-8')
data = json.loads(json_str)
print(data)
```

I am getting this error:

```
JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 2 (char 1)
```

json string is not able to convert into json object.

Comment: the error is on `json.loads(..)`, right? if so, you have to show the value of `json_str` to receive help.

Comment: You're trying to read in a gzipped file as json. I don't know what you expected.

Comment: @Marc https://codebeautify.org/online-json-editor/cb9ebcda
Here is the json_str

Comment: @Aplet123 what's wrong with compressing json data and reading in afterwards??

Comment: [json syntax](https://www.json.org/json-de.html) requires to start with brackets. you can just replace the entire first line with a `{` character

Comment: That's a tar.gz file, not just a .gz file. Use the `tarfile` module to read it.

Comment: @Marc I have already tried it by replacing the first line with `{` character but still getting the same error.

Comment: @shay By replacing first line he probably meant doing `json_str = json_str[json_str.find('{'):]` before `json.loads(...)`. Also see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65277378/941531) for other solutions.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**. As suggested by @CharlesDuffy you have gzipped tar archive with JSON inside. See Second Version for reading gzipped tars. First Version is for reading gzip only.

**First Version**

I think you compressed/decompressed your JSON data somehow wrongly, as it contains non-JSON leading bytes after decompression.

Either you have to cut/remove leading non-JSON bytes from your decompressed data or re-create your data like in code below. For your case to remove leading wrong bytes do `json_str = json_str[json_str.find('{'):]` before `json.loads(...)`.

Down below is full working code of step-by-step json encoding / gzip compressing / writing to file / reading from file / gzip decompressing / json decoding:

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZA/TwQhEMV7PsUkFkCCXPQszCV2amlhY2EsuGP2jssuEOCyuTN@9hXYP/EaKShm3rz3m/HndHB2PQym8y4kOEZnBewvxhNyAy925zSuPoJJSIg/a5UUPME3gfyoohv4vBP3Yv0lxso2V15VG1GQH0KOk7x4Sn3qfGSjhQBjNdqUew@ckIjBqLYIS1NiDWX0lJrbR5r7vUkHcB4to1VQ/fYXKoD2W8pBRWg2FaCRfUFlhV/uXOcDxshGf87LRu@o9OoZS0KZmLIFzGAz85uzKP781f4/knBNsuxUUTQuMI0MGYFlmuo45436Krzafbl5jWqd0pHVmdILxqbppHwYfgE)

```
import json, gzip

# Encode/Write

pydata = {
    'a': [1,2,3],
    'b': False,
}

jdata = json.dumps(pydata, indent = 4)

serial = jdata.encode('utf-8')

with open('data.json.gz', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(gzip.compress(serial))

# Read/Decode
   
serial, pydata, jdata = None, None, None
    
with open('data.json.gz', 'rb') as f:
    serial = gzip.decompress(f.read())
    
jdata = serial.decode('utf-8')

pydata = json.loads(jdata)

print(pydata)
```

Output:

```
{'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': False}
```

---

**Second Version**

Down below is code for reading JSON inside gzipped tar files. It reads first JSON file from tar, you may replace `fname = ...` with correct file name of JSON file if there are several json files.

```
import json, gzip, tarfile, io

with open('data.json.tar.gz', 'rb') as f:
    tserial = gzip.decompress(f.read())
    
with tarfile.open(fileobj = io.BytesIO(tserial), mode = 'r') as f:
    fname = [e for e in f.getnames() if e.lower().endswith('.json')][0]
    serial = f.extractfile(fname).read()
    
jdata = serial.decode('utf-8')

pydata = json.loads(jdata)

print(pydata)
```

Comment: The extra data at the top of the file is a tar header. The OP has a tar.gz file with a JSON file within it, instead of a json.gz file.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks! Added second code snippet for reading gzipped tar with JSON.